# Gmail - Prevent user from sending sensitive mails

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail, gmail-imap, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I want to write a gmail extension that prevents users from sending sensitive information unencrypted.

The idea is to monitor a new email (receiver, subject line, body text and attachment) while the user is composing it and depending on a set of rules detects the sensitivity level.

If high sensitivity level is detected the user is informed with a dialog box and can decide to upload the content of the email to a secure server.

The recipient receives instead of the original email an email with a link where they can log in and retrieve the sensitive content.

Can this be done as a gmail plugin (gadget) or rather as an extension for Chrome (and/or Firefox)? Which is the right API to use here?

Comment: question is too broad. gmail plugin is unrelated.

Comment: could you explain why gmail plugin is unrelated? Thanks!

Comment: gmail plugin is for received mail